# fade in/out not working with pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a pop up and I am trying to get it to fade in and out slowly. I tried to model my code after others trying to apply fade in and out, but for some reason mine is not taking affect.

When I first added the code off of a modeled pop up I saw, it had the fade option in the onclick code like this...

```
onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">
```

and in the code I saw it worked great. Now I am adding the ID's, but nothing happens.

I created a fiddle to show what I am trying to do...

https://jsfiddle.net/51ysjz6y/

Does anyone see anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `class` to `<a>` and remove all the unwanted click `javascript` function and you can just call it as below with `overlay` being displayed:

```
$('.signin').on('click',function(){
    $("#light,.black_overlay").fadeIn("slow");
});

$('.close').on('click',function(){
    $("#light,.black_overlay").fadeOut("slow");
})
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/51ysjz6y/9/)**

---

**UPDATE**

```
<div class="signinbutton"> 
     <a class="signin" href="javascript:void(0)">Sign In</a>
</div>
<div id="light" class="signInpopup">
    <a class="close" href="javascript:void(0)">Close</a>
    <!--Forms and other elements-->
</div>
```

This is your `html` structure now

Comment: When I do what you did, my link doesn't even open the pop up.

Comment: did you check the demo?? as I have mentioned add a class to the `signin` anchor!

Comment: Yes, I did and I'm not sure why nothing is happening. My site is sundayfundayleague.com is it helps to see it? It is just on the index page.

Comment: if you check the `console` in your site you will find an error saying **missing ) after argument list**. So you are missing a bracket which stops js to execute!!

Comment: I found it. Thanks for all of your help!!

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 2):

I updated your fiddle with following

Changed some code to jQuery and removed onclick from div

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/51ysjz6y/7/)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".signinbutton a").click(function() {
            $('#light').fadeIn('slow');
        });

        function fade(id) {
            $("#" + id).fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As the code written in you fiddle:

There is everything you want.

just replace

```
<a class="close" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a>
```

**With**

```
<a class="close" href="javascript:fade('light'); fade('fade');" >Close</a>
```

and

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Sign In</a>
```

**with**

```
<a href="javascript:light('light'); light('fade');">Sign In</a>
```